# How to apply theme changes in websphere portal 8.0?

Tags: java, themes, bootstrapping, portal, websphere-portal

I'm going to add bootstrap framework to webShere portal 8.0 and I'm using this 
http://blog.royalcyber.com/portal-collaboration/how-to-implement-bootstrap-framework-in-ibm-websphere-portal-for-custom-theme/

I installed webSphere portal on my pc and I added bootstrap in it.
when I restart websphere portal it removes all my changes. how could I apply my changes in websphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you making the changes? it sounds like you are making them directly on the file system.

The gist is you either need to connect to webdav of portal and create a new theme list through the admin access point or create a theme in a ear and deploy it to portal.

The static resources are stored on the file system only for cache purposes but are kept in webdav so if you are not making the changes in webdav they will get cleared out
See more here about the intriciacies of creating your own
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Developing%20Themes%20for%20WebSphere%20Portal%208.0.0.1